# Loop in template without context variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is possible to use a loop using just numbers and not context variables in the template something like:

```
{% for (int i = 22; i < 65; ++i) %}
<input id="name_{{i}}" type="number" value="{{i}}">
{% endfor %}
```

If is possible to do how can I do it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```py
for i in range(22,64):
```